# Device does not respond in android

Tags: android

My App is run correctly in simulator but when i try to run in device .i will not give me error

please try to solve this problem

```
07-10 02:56:34.022: D/AndroidRuntime(28052): Shutting down VM
07-10 02:56:34.022: W/dalvikvm(28052): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a551f8)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mobileTimerClock/com.android.mobileTimerClock.TimeClockDashBoard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at com.android.mobileTimerClock.TimeClockDashBoard.onCreate(TimeClockDashBoard.java:394)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-10 02:56:34.022: E/AndroidRuntime(28052):    ... 11 more
07-10 02:56:34.022: W/ActivityManager(177):   Force finishing activity com.android.mobileTimerClock/.TimeClockDashBoard
07-10 02:56:34.030: W/ActivityManager(177):   Force finishing activity com.android.mobileTimerClock/.DashBoard
07-10 02:56:34.530: W/ActivityManager(177): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41d0a690 com.android.mobileTimerClock/.TimeClockDashBoard}
```

Comment: What's in your `onCreate` method of `TimeClockDashBoard`? Specifically, what are you passing to `Log.i()`?

Comment: It looks like you are logging something null. Without code is quite hard to tell you the exact problem. Show us some code to provide a better help.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you're passing null as the second parameter to a `Log.i(String, String)` call (or similar `Log.*()` method):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Comment: very very thanks to your reply.Actually i have two activity.in my second Activity,i fetch data from server.this data is perfectly correct download in simulator but in device ,it will give me above crash report.please help me about it

Comment: @saqibabbasi As ninetwozero says, you are using a Log message with an invalid object.  Find and fix all possible cases of that, though the particular one triggering the crash is at line 394 of TimeClockDashBoard.java   That you get away with it on some devices (such as the emulator) does not make it right.

Comment: I'd recommend that you just put the relevant parts up on github.com/codepad.org so that everyone can help out. You can mark "pastes" as private so that only people that's seen this question will know of your paste. :)

Comment: in line no 394 .. try {
    jParser = new JSONParser();
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //Log.v("Json data From Server: ", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: Then ``e.getMessage()`` is null, ie there is no message with the ``Exception``.

Comment: here is my code
   String url=String.format("url");
      
      try {
    jParser = new JSONParser();
    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   
   
   str=TAG_CONFIG;
   new AyncdataFromServer().execute(str);
   
  str=TAG_CC1HeadingData; 
     new AyncdataFromServer().execute(str);
    str=TAG_CC2HeadingData;
     new AyncdataFromServer().execute(str);
     str=TAG_CC3HeadingData;
     new AyncdataFromServer().execute(str);
     str=TAG_CC4HeadingData;
     new AyncdataFromServer().execute(str);

Comment: Well, that *might* work out, but there seems to be an underlying issue. :)

Comment: i have 4 spinner controller .each one is filled from server data.i have did this through asyncTask.

Comment: Well, that might work out, but there seems to be an underlying issue.Can you please explain it